# PHP error - The first argument to copy() function cannot be a directory in

Tags: php

I'm trying to move all images files from folder into another folder but i'm having this warning and i can't go further, did some search here but not getting the desired solution

having those errors

> Warning: copy(): The first argument to copy() function cannot be a directory in /home/XXX/public_html/miga/db/teste.php on line 16

> Warning: copy(): The first argument to copy() function cannot be a directory in /home/XXX/public_html/miga/db/teste.php on line 16

> Warning: copy(): The first argument to copy() function cannot be a directory in /home/XXX/public_html/miga/db/teste.php on line 16

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$files = scandir("../uploads");
$source = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/miga/uploads/';
$haveImages = glob($source."*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}", GLOB_BRACE);
$keepFiles = array('miga.png');
$destination = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/miga/media/';
if(!empty($haveImages)){
    echo $source;
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        if (in_array($file, array(".",".."))
        ) continue;
        // If we copied this successfully, mark it for deletion
        if (copy($source.$file, $destination.$file)) {
            $delete[] = $source.$file;
            $gravacao[] = $source.$destination;
        }
    }
}
else{
    echo  "here 0";
}
```

Comment: So make a debug output, and check what `$source.$file` actually contains at this point ...?

Comment: debug show me files and one folder...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check with [is_file](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.is-file.php)

```php
...
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        if (in_array($file, array(".",".."))
        ) continue;

         if(!is_file($source.$file)) {
           continue;
         }
        // If we copied this successfully, mark it for deletion
        if (copy($source.$file, $destination.$file)) {
            $delete[] = $source.$file;
            $gravacao[] = $source.$destination;
        }
    }
```